# How do I extract out just the player names in r

Tags: r, stringr

I have an object called `kemba_walker`, which contains these characters:

`"  Kemba Walker PG  |  #8"`

How can I extract out `Kemba Walker PG` using `stringr`?

I think I can use `kemba_walker %>% str_extract("")` but I don't know regex, so I have no idea what pattern to put inside the function!

Comment: Can you show few more entries of your data ? What would be the rule to extract the player name ? Do you need first two words of every entry or text before `"|"` or something else ?

Comment: Ronak, I need the first two words of every entry

Comment: @HowardBaek OK, but does every entry have only two name words?  What about someone with a middle name?  Would you then only want to capture the first and middle name?

Comment: Okay guys, to keep things simple, I want ALL the characters coming before `|`. So, I'd want `Kemba Walker PG`

Comment: That way, I can capture the players with a middle name, as @TimBiegeleisen mentioned

Comment: Just edited my question @akrun

Comment: @akrun But, just because the OP requested the `stringr` library does not mean that using it is the best answer here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree that, but the OP mentioned in two places about using `stringr`

Comment: It is a pipe delimited text, so import as such: `read.table(text = "  Kemba Walker PG  |  #8", sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove everything after `"|"`

```
vec <- "  Kemba Walker PG  |  #8"

trimws(sub("\\|.*", "", vec))
#[1] "Kemba Walker PG"
```

As @zx8754 mentions we can also use `read.table`

```
read.table(text = vec, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the pipe as the marker for how to find the player name:

```
input <- "  Kemba Walker PG  |  #8"
name <- sub("^\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\|.*$", "\\1", input)
name

[1] "Kemba Walker PG"
```

The regex works by capturing the player name in `(.*?)`.  The replacement, which is the second argument to `sub`, is `\1`, which is the capture group.

Comment: What does `"\\1"` mean?

Comment: @akrun It's never always clear to me whether something is an _exact_ duplicate.  There are many more duplicates from what I can see on other tags, such as regex and SQL.

Comment: I was also hesitant first because the OP mentioned a stringr solution, but then II find exact pattern with `sub`.  But, closing a question with dupe increases chance of finding it through google

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_remove` from `stringr` to remove the character `|` followed by other characters `.*`

```
library(stringr)
trimws(str_remove(str1, "\\|.*"))
#[1] "Kemba Walker PG"
```

---

Or using `str_extract` to extract characters other than `|` from the start (`^`) of the string

```
trimws(str_extract(str1, "^[^|]+")
#[1] "Kemba Walker PG"
```

---

Or in `base R` with only `trimws`

```
trimws(str1,  whitespace = "\\s*[|].*|\\s*", which = 'both')
#[1] "Kemba Walker PG"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "  Kemba Walker PG  |  #8"
```